# CDC::DrawText doesn't work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I get an error: Debug Assertion Failed at my myDC.DrawText?
If I remove that line, the graphics work fine.

```
CPaintDC dc(this);

CBitmap myBmp;
CDC myDc;

HANDLE h = ::LoadImage(NULL,"C:\\lady.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
myBmp.Attach(h);

myDc.DrawText("Hello",CRect(10,10,100,30),DT_CENTER);  // Debug Assertion Failed


myDc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
myDc.SelectObject(&myBmp);
dc.BitBlt(20,10,436,363,&myDc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're drawing the text before actually creating the DC.  Move the  DrawText line below the CreateCompatibleDB line.

Comment: That helped with the error.  But I am not seeing the text?  I also tried using CDC::TextOut and see no text?

Comment: You don't really say what you're trying to achieve here.  If you want to draw text on top of an image, put the DrawText LAST after the BitBlt, otherwise the BitBlt will draw the bitmap on top of the text (most likely obscuring the text completely)

Comment: Did do it last... nothing? Is there a font that I have to specify somewhere?

Comment: Whoops, I read the code wrong.  It should be: 1. CreateCompatibleDc 2. SelectObject(&myBmp) 3. DrawText, 4. BitBlt back to the PaintDC.  Here's an article on this  kind of thing: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6271/Rendering-text-on-top-of-a-bitmap